# Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms ArgumentError - too few arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I get a Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms  ArgumentError - too few arguments when I click on the link to display my modal. I am not sure why:

I have a link that directs to images#show. However I want to use bootstrap modal to display the image instead without reloading the page.

Here is my link that is supposed to display a modal when clicked on. The link

```
- url = @entry.class.to_s.downcase.singularize
= link_to(send("#{url}_path", @entry), data: { remote:true, 'type' =>    @entry.class.to_s.downcase }) do
    = yield
```

This link is in my home#index.

Here is my images # show controller:

```
def show
    authorize! :view, @image
    @can_destroy = can?('delete_asset', @image)
    @can_edit = can?('edit_metadata', @image)
    format.js
    format.json
end
```

My _modal view template is :

```
<div id="contact-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
      Moussa Testing the Modals
      <div class="modal-body">
        Me testing again
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        Moussa testing encore.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I added a show.js.erb in the image views for ajax:

```
$('<%= j render "modalview" %>').modal();
```

Should I modify the link ? How ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have element you wrote instead. Try to change script in shows.js.erb with this

```
$('#modal_element').replaceWith('<%= j render "modalview" %>').modal();
```

in your main view add this snippet ;

```
<div id="modal_element">
</div>
```

Comment: What  do you mean by main view ?